# Configure Solr to perform case-insensitive sort on values

Tags: sorting, solr, lucene, case-insensitive

I have a field-name called "customer" contains the following values,

1. Brooks Sports
2. AM-Records
3. 1elememt
4. ALTAVISTA
5. Adidas
6. 3gdata
7. Apple
8. BMW
9. 7eleven
10. bic corporation

    customer field in solr schema.xml

    ```
    <field docValues="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="customer" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
    ```

I need to perform case-insensitive sort on above customer values. so i can get the data as follow,

1. 1elememt
2. 3gdata
3. 7eleven
4. Adidas
5. ALTAVISTA
6. AM-Records
7. Apple
8. bic corporation
9. BMW
10. Brooks Sports

for this i create a new copyField named "customer_sort"
field in scheme.xml

```
        <field docValues="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="customer_sort" stored="false" type="LowerTextField"/>
```

fieldType in scheme.xml

```
        <fieldType name="LowerTextField" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="1000">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

copyfield in scheme.xml

```
<copyField source="customer" dest="customer_sort"/>
```

currently the sort result is

1. 1elememt
2. 3gdata
3. 7eleven
4. ALTAVISTA
5. AM-Records
6. Adidas
7. Apple
8. BMW
9. Brooks Sports
10. bic corporation

sort happening based on ascii value. i.e.(A then a, B then b,...).

Same happen when i tried alphaOnlySort.

Can anybody please tell me what i'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: What does your sort query look like? What does the analysis page for the field show when indexing values? If the tokens aren't being lowercased, the sort won't work - and you'll have to reindex after adding the copyField definition. There is no need to give separate `index` and `query` chains if they're identical.

Comment: @MatsLindh i checked the scheme_builder for the "customer_sort" copyfield. all the indexing is happened in lowercase.

Comment: @MatsLindh Please take a look on the attached images, fo rmy solrquery and scheme_browser for customer_sort.

Comment: Did you reindex after changing the definition? What does the analysis page (not analyzer) show for index/query values?

Answer (score 0):

@MatsLindh Please find the images for [Solr_query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6PbD.png) and [analyzer_screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht8Rc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this in schema.xml and also you have mentioned **type="TextField"**. I would like to know about that.

```
<fieldType name="LowerTextField" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="1000">
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Comment: This will split the text into separate tokens, which is not usable for getting a valid sort.